# Lighthouse Report via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, automation, lighthouse

I'm trying to open the default web browser Chrome, not one headless, with Lighthouse, because I need to be logged in to my Google account.

--chrome-flags                 Custom flags to pass to Chrome (space-delimited).

Check the bellow link to make an idea about the --chrome-flags. 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse

```
    stream = os.popen('lighthouse --chrome-flags="--headless"--disable-storage-reset="true" --preset=' +
                      preset + ' --output=json --output-path='+relative_path + name+'_'+getdate+'.report.json ' + url)
```

How can I change the '--chrome-flags' to open my installed Chrome app, not one headless?

Answer (score 0):

try changing `--chrome-flags="--headless"` to `--chrome-flags="--headed"`